# Route53に登録したホストゾーンを名前解決できない

Tags: aws, dns

Route53に登録したホストゾーンexample.jpに下記のレコードを登録しています。

```
example.jp.        NS     ns-356.awsdns-44.com. ほか3つのネームサーバー
example.jp.        SOA    ns-356.awsdns-44.com. awsdns-hostmaster.amazon.com.
www.example.jp.    A      3.113.XXX.XXX
```

3.113.XXX.XXXはEC2にアタッチしたEIPです。
このドメインはお名前.comで取得したドメインで、お名前.comのネームサーバー情報には上記NSレコードのネームサーバーを4つすべて設定しています。

設定後、数時間経った状態ではブラウザのアドレスにwww.example.jpを入力し意図したとおりEC2に接続することが可能でしたが、数日経ってからもう一度接続しようとしたところ、今度は接続できなくなっていました。
IP直打ちならEC2に接続可能です。

nslookupの結果を確認したところ、example.jp、www.example.jpともにNon-existent domainとなりましたが、
Route53のNSレコードに登録されているネームサーバーを指定してnslookupを実施したところ、
example.jpでは名前の応答が、www.example.jpでは名前とAddressの応答がありました。

どうしてこのような結果になるのかよくわかりません。
どうすればブラウザのアドレスにwww.example.jpを入力してEC2に接続することができるでしょうか。

よろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

自己解決しました。

メールアドレスの有効性を確認するメールが来ていたのを見落としていたのが原因でした。
このメール中の有効性確認リンクを踏み、しばらく待つとhoge.example.jpで接続できるようになりました。

Answer (score 1):

所有するドメインが`example.jp`の場合、`hoge.example.jp.`ではなく`example.jp.`ホストゾーンを作成する必要があります。その上で、Route 53から提示された`example.jp. NS`レコードのネームサーバをお名前.comに登録する必要があります。

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。当初の質問が「実在する可能性であるドメイン名ではなく例示用のドメイン名を使用すべき」とのことで編集されたため、example.jp相当のホストゾーンを記述していたはずがhoge.example.jpホストゾーンに書き換わっております（現在は再再編集で当初意図通りの質問に戻しています）。